# How can I test external HDDs after 3 computers fail to turn on after using external HDDs?

Tags: external-hard-drive, hardware-failure, desktop-computer

In the same week, I’ve had 3 computers fail to turn on when being connected to my two external HDDs. The drives are a LaCie 500Gb and an IBM 250Gb in an OWC case. Both connect through Firewire 800 or eSata.

The external HDDs have been continuously connected but lightly used since 2011. They are daisy chained to each other by Firewire 800. Internet access has been turned off for the last 5 years.

What type of test and what type of test professional should I look for to test the HDDs? Voltage spikes? Apple certified repair can’t test the HDDs.

Comment: Do the computers turn on without the external drives connected?

Answer (score 0):

All external HDDs I've seen are just normal HDDs in an enclosure which has a some sort of converter. There is a good chance it the electronics in the enclosure that is causing the issues, while the drives are fine. Do they have external power supplies? Because they can go bad as well (and a local power spike might cause both of them to go bad at the same time).

Personally, I would take the drives out of the enclosure to be able to test the enclosure and the drives separately. If you have any system that has a free SATA port you can just connect the internal drives directly. If that works you can at least get to your data. It's not that hard to connect a hard drive, so you should be able to do it yourself. But any local PC shop should be able to help you if needed. (They might have some issues getting data of a Mac formatted drive, but they should be able to tell you if it's broken or not.)

If the drives are good this would mean the enclosure needs replacement, but I'd also suggest that 13 year old drives are up for replacement as well if they are used to store anything important.

If that does not work and the drives are defective, you need to look for a company that does data recovery. They generally won't save the drive, just try to the data of them. That's often not cheap, your data may not be worth it, but that's up to you.